# Pending Post review notification for contributors

Tags: dashboard

I've been looking around at this for solutions but strangely I can't seem to find one that appears decent - maybe I haven't looked hard enough.

What I want is a notification on my dashboard when posts are pending review. I can't believe this doesn't seem to be core behaviour for WP. I so far can't seem to find any recent plugins for this, maybe it's a setting I haven't noticed on WP.

Any help gratefully appreciated.

Jonathon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jonnny,

I would highly recommend checking out Edit Flow. It does add a notification to the dashboard about Pending posts, as well as a host of other things. The plugin is aimed at organizing a whole team of content creators. It's well described at editflow.org.

Answer (score 0):

I'll throw in WP Status Notifier, which doesn't add a notification in the backend, but can send you and others an email that a post is pending along with a link to moderate it. I also like it because you can set it to send an email to the writer when you publish it or send it back to draft.